# Forward iMessages and SMS to e-mail?

Tags: ios, messages, sms

I want to forward all SMS and iMessages received on my iPhone to my e-mail address. I have tried [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/), but can't see a way to do it. Has anyone else managed to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> you need to have your email address turned on for iMessage on your
>   iPhone in order to enable Text Message Forwarding. If you don’t, the
>   numeric access code will not appear on your iPad or Mac during the
>   setup process. As soon as you enable your email address for iMessage
>   (you only need to do this on your iPhone) the numeric access codes
>   appear as expected. Once you have text message forwarding setup you
>   can disable your email address again in iMessage as it seems to only
>   be necessary for the numeric access code setup step, not the actual
>   text message forwarding itself.`
>
> To enable your email in Messages, grab your iPhone and head to
>   Settings > Messages > Send & Receive. There, you’ll find all of the
>   addresses at which you can be reached via iMessage. Enable your iCloud
>   email address by tapping on it, then head back to your Mac or iPad and
>   again request the pairing verification code from the Messages app.
>   This time, you should see a box appear on your iPhone in which you can
>   enter the code.

Source: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/sms-relay-configuration-fix/

Comment: What about SMSes? (no iMessages here)